# More efficient conversion of tab-formatted nested data structure to json

Tags: python, parsing, recursion, json

I have data that looks like the "Input" below and need to convert it into JSON.  My solution works by parsing the text to find a level for each data point.  Then I use a recursive structure to build a JSON tree (or maybe its not JSON, but its much more useful than the original format).

First, I transform the input in the following way.

Input:

```
person:
    address:
        street1: 123 Bar St
        street2: 
        city: Madison
        state: WI
        zip: 55555
    web:
        email: boo@baz.com
```

First-step output:

```
[{'name':'person','value':'','level':0},
 {'name':'address','value':'','level':1},
 {'name':'street1','value':'123 Bar St','level':2},
 {'name':'street2','value':'','level':2},
 {'name':'city','value':'Madison','level':2},
 {'name':'state','value':'WI','level':2},
 {'name':'zip','value':55555,'level':2},
 {'name':'web','value':'','level':1},
 {'name':'email','value':'boo@baz.com','level':2}]
```

This is easy to accomplish with `split(':')` and by counting the number of leading tabs:

```
def tab_level(astr):
    """Count number of leading tabs in a string
    """
    return len(astr)- len(astr.lstrip('\t'))
```

Then I feed the first-step output into the following function:

```
def ttree_to_json(ttree,level=0):
    result = {}
    for i in range(0,len(ttree)):
        cn = ttree[i]
        try:
            nn  = ttree[i+1]
        except:
            nn = {'level':-1}

        # Edge cases
        if cn['level']>level:
            continue
        if cn['level']<level:
            return result

        # Recursion
        if nn['level']==level:
            dict_insert_or_append(result,cn['name'],cn['value'])
        elif nn['level']>level:
            rr = ttree_to_json(ttree[i+1:], level=nn['level'])
            dict_insert_or_append(result,cn['name'],rr)
        else:
            dict_insert_or_append(result,cn['name'],cn['value'])
            return result
    return result
```

where:

```
def dict_insert_or_append(adict,key,val):
    """Insert a value in dict at key if one does not exist
    Otherwise, convert value to list and append
    """
    if key in adict:
        if type(adict[key]) != list:
            adict[key] = [adict[key]]
        adict[key].append(val)
    else:
        adict[key] = val
```

The approach is redundant and therefore inefficient.  I also wonder whether the solution is robust (for example, I had to modify the code to accommodate repeated tags).  Think of the Input above as a formatting for SGML.  Any suggestions for improvement would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the format of the file constant, meaning there will always be those attributes present. For example, person will always have address and web and address will always have those property? If so then you can just read person by person assuming file format doesn't change

Comment: I can see how that would work for addresses.  Unfortunately, the example is just an example.  I need something that works for arbitrary tags.

Comment: Is there some sort of structure to the input. Are the data field always tab separated such that the tabbed line belongs to the parent above with one less tab?

Comment: Ah yes.  Sorry if that was not clear.  The data is structured such that tabs denote a parent-child relationship.  Similar to the structure of python code.

Comment: Just want to paint the problem clearer. Is 'person' the key or the value? In your example you parse it as `name=person` with `value=''`

Comment: What you basically want to do is apply the iterative algorithm version of post tree transversal. Wiki has an easy article on it. Thus while reading it, you keep a stack of data and populate to correct parent as you transverse iteratively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not programmed in python but you should be able to do this in one shot. In pseudo-code it should be something like so:

```
function parseJsonInput (file)
   var parsedJson= {};
   var parentStack = [parsedJson]
   for each line in file
     var data = parseLine(line) //return key,value,level. null if not avail for each field

     //leaf item process it by adding it to its current parent
     if data.value is not null
        var currentParent = parentStack.getLastElement()
        currentParent[data.key] = data.value
        var nextLineLevel = parseLine( peekNextLine() ).level; //peek next line level
        if nextLineLevel = data.level - 1
          parentStack.pop() //done processing child, about to go back to parent
     else 
        //group node, push it as the new parent and keep on processing. 
        //created more variable than needed for clarity
        var currentParent = parentStack.getLastElement()
        currentParent[data.key] = {}
        var newParent = currentParent[data.key]
        parentStack.push( newParent )
   endfor

    return parsedJson;

end function
```

I haven't tried that but that should work give or take few bugs. But the basic idea as I mentioned in the comment is to transverse the file iteratively as a tree structure using iterative post-tree-transversal method. I'm not sure if the 'peekNextLine' is available to you, if not then you would need another variable to keep track of the last level processed and strategically insert that logic there -- I started doing this, but figured it might be confusing at first. Let me know if there is some issues. I can help. If I have time I can even write a quick javascript version for you to learn from.

Comment: Thank you user\d+.  Using a stack is probably a better solution... and more transparent!  Still, I am curious about an improved recursive solution.  Is it possible to achieve the same level of efficiency with a recursive solution?

Comment: Can you please convert it to Javascript code

Comment: @LaxmikantDange sorry bud no incentive for me

Answer (score 1):

#### Practical tips

Instead of:

> ```
> try:
>     nn = ttree[i+1]
> except:
>     nn = {'level': -1}
> ```

This should have been:

```
if i + 1 < len(ttree):
    nn = ttree[i + 1]
else:
    nn = {'level': -1}
```

try/except is for handling *anomalies*: things that shouldn't happen under normal circumstances. Take for example an inventory service, with an API method `get_item(item_id)`. Callers of the API are expected to use valid item ids. If a user asks for a non-existent item that's an anomaly. So when loading the item with `item_id` from the backend storage, you would assume the query will work, and handle the case of non-existent items with a try/except.

In your program, the case of `i + 1 >= len(ttree)` happens during normal operations, when processing the last line of input. This is not an anomaly, as it happens for perfectly legal inputs too. This is a case for checking with an `if` instead of try/except.

Abusing try/except can sometimes hurt performance too.
One time in the past I misunderstood the "ask forgiveness not permission" rule and changed many of my ifs to try/except in a program where this would happen a few dozens of times. During my tests, the speed difference was noticeable even without a timer. try/except is the right tool for handling anomalies, things that are not supposed to happen during normal operations.

---

Don't check for the type of an object like this:

> ```
> if type(adict[key]) != list:
> ```

Use the `isinstance` built-in function instead:

```
if isinstance(adict[key], list):
```

---

Instead of `range(0, n)` you can write `range(n)`, it's the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @janos!  I was not aware of the `isinstance()` method, thank you for pointing that out.  Regarding your first tip, I was under the impression that asking for forgiveness is more pythonic.  See, for example, this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain).  Alex Martelli does it too, see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592565/determine-if-variable-is-defined-in-python).  Does try-except really make programs run slower?  Do you have a source to support that assertion?

Comment: Alex Martelli says try/except is for "anomalous situations", and that's exactly what I meant with "for handling exceptional events that shouldn't happen under normal circumstances". If I understand your program correctly, it will pass through the `except` during normal operations, for example when you parse the example input, which is a valid input, and there is no anomaly here.

Comment: Thanks @janos!  I found another example of exceptions being used in non-anomalous situations... Python's `iter` protocol.  See, for example, this [tutorial](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html).

Comment: I suppose you're talking about the implementation of the `take` function? That's still an anomalous situation: trying to take `n` items from a sequence that has less than `n` items doesn't really make sense, so that's kind of an anomaly.